# Applying mix() to textures with an alpha channel results in artifacts

Tags: opengl, glsl

I have two textures: a cat and a wall, both images are loaded using QImage, have the same size(512x512), and are loaded in PNG format (QImage::Format_ARGB32).

```
//Load texture image
QImage imgWallTexture(":Scenes/Sc5Texture/textures/wall512x512.png");
if(imgWallTexture.isNull()) {
    qInfo("[ERROR] initScene: image texture load failed!");
    return;
}
imgWallTexture = QGLWidget::convertToGLFormat(imgWallTexture);


//Load texture image
QImage imgCatTexture(":Scenes/Sc5Texture/textures/cat512x512.png");
if(imgCatTexture.isNull()) {
    qInfo("[ERROR] initScene: image texture load failed!");
    return;
}
imgCatTexture = QGLWidget::convertToGLFormat(imgCatTexture);

//Texture ID(name)
unsigned int wallTexture = 0;
unsigned int catTexture = 0;
//Allocate 1 buffer for textures
glFunctions->glGenTextures(1, &wallTexture);
glFunctions->glGenTextures(1, &catTexture);
//Select wall texture
glFunctions->glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, wallTexture);
//Load data to texture
glFunctions->glTexImage2D(GL_TEXTURE_2D, //selected texture type
             0, //mipmap level(we generate him using OpenGL)
             GL_RGBA, //texture data format
             imgWallTexture.width(),
             imgWallTexture.height(),
             0, //always zero
             GL_RGBA, //image format
             GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, //image data format
             imgWallTexture.bits() //image data
            );

if(glFunctions->glGetError() != GL_NO_ERROR) {
    qInfo("[ERROR] initScene: glTexImage2D failed!");
    return;
}

//Generate mipmap for texture
glFunctions->glGenerateMipmap(GL_TEXTURE_2D);

//Setting up texture
//Texture draw
glFunctions->glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_S, GL_REPEAT);
glFunctions->glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_T, GL_REPEAT);
//Texture filtration
glFunctions->glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER, GL_LINEAR_MIPMAP_NEAREST);
glFunctions->glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER, GL_LINEAR);

//Select cat texture
glFunctions->glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, catTexture);



//Select wall texture
glFunctions->glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, catTexture);
//Load data to texture
glFunctions->glTexImage2D(GL_TEXTURE_2D, //selected texture type
             0, //mipmap level(we generate him using OpenGL)
             GL_RGBA, //texture data format
             imgCatTexture.width(),
             imgCatTexture.height(),
             0, //always zero
             GL_RGBA, //image format
             GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, //image data format
             imgCatTexture.bits() //image data
            );

if(glFunctions->glGetError() != GL_NO_ERROR) {
    qInfo("[ERROR] initScene: glTexImage2D failed!");
    return;
}

//Generate mipmap for texture
glFunctions->glGenerateMipmap(GL_TEXTURE_2D);

//Setting up texture
//Texture draw
glFunctions->glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_S, GL_REPEAT);
glFunctions->glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_T, GL_REPEAT);
//Texture filtration
glFunctions->glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER, GL_LINEAR_MIPMAP_NEAREST);
glFunctions->glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER, GL_LINEAR);

//Unselect texture
glFunctions->glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0);
```

In my fragment shader code, I use the mix() function to mix the texture.

```
#version 450 core
out vec4 FragColor;
in vec2 wallTexCoord;
in vec2 catTexCoord;

uniform float mixValue;

//for texture
uniform sampler2D wallTexture;
uniform sampler2D catTexture;

void main()
{
    FragColor = mix(texture(wallTexture, wallTexCoord), texture(catTexture, catTexCoord), mixValue);
}
```

If mixValue = 0, then I see a normal wall.

[image: Scr when mixValue = 0]

If mixValue = 1, then I see a normal cat with no artifacts.

[image: Scr when mixValue = 1]

But if the mixValue is closer to 1, then I get artifacts:

[image: Scr when mixValue closer to 1]

I thought that there were some artifacts in the pictures, but I ran both images through Photoshop to avoid internal artifacts in the image.

How do I fix this?

Comment: Are you using premultiplied alpha? It seems like you might not be, and therefore you might want to multiply the .rgb of each texture by its .a before mixing

Comment: @Andrea, Now I convert the image to QImage::Format_ARGB32_Premultiplied and it works as it should.

Thank you so much for your reply!
You can forward your comment in answer and I will mark it as a solution.

Comment: Glad to help! By the way, does Photoshop have a “do not save colour values for transparent pixels” option like GIMP? That might reduce the artifacts you see. Nonetheless, processing the image to use premultiplied alpha is usually the best solution. You can ideally do that as part of an asset pipeline.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The artefacts are caused by unexpected colour data in transparent texels. An easy fix is to use premultiplied alpha.